# bibtex part of author missing

Tags: bibtex

I'm having a problem with author display for a statute - the author is 'City and County of San Francisco' but the output (using the `apalike.bst` style file provided by Elsevier) gives the author as 'City and San Francisco', missing the 'County' in the authorname.  Any suggestions?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: Apart from @egreg 's answer, would not be that more an editor?

Comment: @mafp - In general, it's entirely possible to have a "corporate" author. I guess we don't know anything else about the entry, and thus can't decide whether `editor` or `author` is more appropriate in this case.

Answer (score 7):

Based on the rules of BibTeX, an input such as

```
author={City and County of San Francisco},
```

specifies two authors because `and` is a keyword and denotes the separator between authors. The first author has only a family name, "City"; the second author has given name "County", 'von' part "of", and family name "San Francisco". Yes, indeed. :)

You can override this default parsing of the `author` field by using an additional pair of braces:

```
author={{City and County of San Francisco}},
```

Now, BibTeX will treat it as an author with a single (though fairly long, of course) name.
This treatment is appropriate for the names of "corporate" authors in general.

Comment: Fantastic - that worked.  Thanks so much!