# Correct representation of an institution as author while citing

Tags: bibliographies, citing, apa-style

I am new to using LaTeX and ran into the following problem. I make use of the `apacite` package. I made a `.bib` file with the following entry:

```
@misc{Ambulancezorkort,

  author = {Rijksinstituut voor gezondheid en milieu, Ministerie van Volksgezondheid Welzijn en Sport},
  title = {Ambulancezorg kort en bondig.},
  month = {March},
  year = {2012},
  url = {http://www.nationaalkompas.nl/zorg/ambulancezorg/ambulancezorg-samengevat/}
```

}

So this autor (a Dutch ministry) is pretty long and has a comma in it. When using `\citeA{Ambulancezorkort}` I've got the following result:

> (Rijksinstituut voor gezondheid en milieu, 2012)

Of course I would like to have the whole name, and not only the part before the comma. When I tried the name without the comma, the outcome was only worse. When using the entry:

```
author = {Rijksinstituut voor gezondheid en milieu Ministerie van Volksgezondheid Welzijn en Sport},
```

I obtain the result:

> (Voor gezondheid en milieu Ministerie van Volksgezondheid Welzijn en Sport, 2012)

So the word 'rijksinstituut' is missing, both in text as in the reference list. 
I am looking for the way of displaying this long author entry correctly. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Authors are separated by `and`. I can't understand the phrase inside author but you can use extra braces: `author = {{Rijksinstituut voor gezondheid en milieu Ministerie van Volksgezondheid Welzijn en Sport}},` if the author name is one name.

Comment: Because you haven't marked the author field with double braces (see Marco Daniel's comment), BibTeX interprets the comma in the first example as separating the (in this case multiple!) `surname` parts from the (in this case multiple!) given names. Clearly not what's intended! In the second case, it interprets `Rijksinstituut` as the given name and `voor gezondheid en milieu` as the "von part" of the author's name -- still not what you want! See [Line break in citation with organization as author](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/102956/5001) for more information on this matter.

Comment: The issue of how to set up "corporate" authors was also discussed recently in [Line break in citation with organization as author](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/103410/5001).