# insert URL in reference; change italic for volume no. to upright; get a full author name, chapter book reference

Tags: bibtex, natbib, chicago-style

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsthm,amsfonts}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{longtable}
\bibliographystyle{chicago}
\setcitestyle{notesep={: }}
```

I am using package `natbib` and bibliography style `chicago`. Its settings are close to what I want, but there are some things that should be changed. If anyone knows to, please help me! The paragraph in bold is what I get from latex, and the next one is what I am looking for.

---

1) I want to have the non-abbreviated name for **only this entry** because it is not person's name. I also want to provide the Url after the title.

**Börse, D. (2002). Deutsche börse rejects porsche’s criticism of quarterly
reports.**

Deutsche Börse (2002). Deutsche börse rejects porsche’s criticism of quarterly
reports. Available at http://deutsche-boerse.com [Accessed 24.11.2009].

---

2) I want to change italic for the volume number (22) to upright font, and I want to replace the `,` (comma) in front the page numbers with a `:` (colon).

**John, T. A. (1993). Accounting measures of corporate liquidity, leverage,
and costs of financial distress. *Financial Management 22* (3), 91–100.**

John, T. A. (1993). Accounting measures of corporate liquidity, leverage,
and costs of financial distress. *Financial Management* 22 (3): 91–100.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Welcome to TeX.SE!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436/5001)

The solution to the first part of your **first question**, about getting the author to be displayed as `Deutsche Börse` rather than as `Börse, D.`, is not related to any particular bibliography style but to the way one should enter "corporate" authors in BibTeX. To signal to BibTeX that a given author's name is "corporate" -- and hence doesn't consist of a first name, potentially some middle name(s), potentially a "von" component, and a surname -- you need to encase it in dual curly braces:

```
author = {{Deutsche B{\"o}rse}},
```

That way, it'll also get sorted under "D" rather than under "B", which is probably what you want, right? :-) For a discussion of why you should want to write `B{\"o}rse` rather than `Börse`, I suggest you read [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/57745/5001) to the question "How to write “ä” and other umlauts and accented letters in bibliography?" (Shameless self-citation alert!) For much more information regarding the formatting of names of corporate authors in `author` and `editor` fields, check out either [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/103418/5001) or [that answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/102957/5001).

Incidentally, you should really also aim to prevent the words `Börse` and `Porsche` in the `title` field from being converted to all-lowercase letters. You can do so by encasing them in curly braces:

```
title  = {Deutsche {B{\"o}rse} rejects {Porsche's} criticism of quarterly reports},
```

You don't indicate *which* entry type you use for this entry, so I'll assume it's the `@misc` type. Assuming the `hyperref` package is loaded as well, the following entry should deliver the goods for you (when used with the `chicago` bibliography style):

```
@misc{db:2002,
   author = {{Deutsche B{\"o}rse}},
   title  = {Deutsche {B{\"o}rse} rejects {Porsche's} criticism of quarterly reports},
   year   = 2002,
   howpublished = {Available at \url{http://deutsche-boerse.com} [Accessed 24. 11. 2009]},
}
```

---

To achieve your **second set of objectives**, viz., to get the volume number printed in upright rather than italic style *and* to replace the comma after the issue number with a column, it's necessary to edit the file `chicago.bst` a bit:

- Locate the file `chicago.bst` in your TeX distribution and make a copy of this file; name the copy, say, `mychicago.bst`. Do *not* edit original files directly.
- Open the file `mychicago.bst` in your favorite text editor and locate the function named `format.jour.vol`. (It starts on line 697 in my copy of this file.)
- A few lines down from the header line of the function, locate the line

  ```
          volume emphasize.space
  ```

  Replace it with

  ```
          volume
  ```

  (I.e., remove the string `emphasize.space`.)

  - A few more lines down, still in the same function, locate the line

    ```
      { ", " *  pages n.dashify * }
    ```

  and replace it with

  ```
        { ": " *  pages n.dashify * }
  ```
- Save the file `mychicago.bst`, either in the directory where your main `.tex` file is located or in a directory that's searched by your TeX distribution. If you take the latter approach, be sure to update the TeX filename database in a way that's appropriate for your TeX distribution.

Finally, replace the directive `\bibliographystyle{chicago}` directive with, you guessed it, `\bibliographystyle{mychicago}`. Re-run BibTeX and LaTeX twice more to fully update the typesetting of the references. Specifically, if your bib entry looks like this:

```
@article{john:1993,
   author = {Teresa A. John},
   title  = {Accounting measures of corporate liquidity, leverage, and costs 
             of financial distress},
   journal= {Financial Management},
   year   = 1993,
   volume = 22,
   number = 3,
   pages  = {91--100},
}
```

the typeset entry should like this:

[image]